# laravel javascript on click gets same id for all buttons in table

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have button in my table like:

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
<tr>
  //other td's...
  <td><button class="btn btn-block btn-theme02 pay-button" id="{{$order->id}}" type="submit">Pay!</button></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

And JavaScript like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.pay-button').click(function (event) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
      });
    event.preventDefault();
    // $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    var prdfoId = $(".kghgh").val();
        $.ajax({
          url: '{{url("orderspayonline")}}/'+encodeURI(prdfoId),
          type: "POST",
          cache: false,

          success: function(data) {
//codes...
}
});
    });
</script>
```

the issue is i get same `order id` for my pay button in all tr's.

> I mean If my order id is `1` i get `5` and if my order id is `2` i get
>   `5` and so on. (5 is latest order id in database)

Comment: Do you see the correct order ID on those buttons if you inspect from the dev tools?

Comment: Because you are taking id value with html class attribute which will take the value when first class is encountered.

Comment: @Nisarg yes i do.

Comment: var prdfoId = $(".kghgh").val(); what is this line contained?

Comment: @Kasnady it gets `{{order->id}} for my route is hidden input.

Comment: @SagarGautam any suggestion?

Comment: @mafortis where is `kghgh` class in the blade file ?

Comment: @SagarGautam yes is in my `tr` (table)

Comment: @mafortis refer to answer

Comment: You need to get Id value like `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: @SagarGautam i get `undefined`

Comment: define this as variable at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach to do such task is to use data attribute. Change `id="{{$order->id}}"`  to `data-id="{{$order->id}}"` and you can get particular id by calling `$(this).data('id')` in jQuery. See below:

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
<tr>
  //other td's...
  <td><button class="btn btn-block btn-theme02 pay-button" data-id="{{$order->id}}" type="submit">Pay!</button></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.pay-button').click(function (event) {
    var prdfoId = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
      });
    event.preventDefault();
    // $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $.ajax({
          url: '{{url("orderspayonline")}}/'+encodeURI(prdfoId),
          type: "POST",
          cache: false,

          success: function(data) {
//codes...
}
});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i get `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are getting wrong id cause you are using this

```
var prdfoId = $(".kghgh").val();
```

Which only 1 input with a fix value. In order to get actual value, you had put `orderId` at every button as their `id`. You can use this for your need in js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.pay-button').click(function (event) {
    var prdfoId = $(this).attr("id"); // here will get the correct id
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
      });
    event.preventDefault();
    // $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $.ajax({
          url: '{{url("orderspayonline")}}/'+encodeURI(prdfoId),
          type: "POST",
          cache: false,

          success: function(data) {
//codes...
}
});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i get `undefined`